# PHP : Variable does not show value in Function while shows directely

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a problem in my code. I post some field data for addsms.php file.

```
  <form id="signup" Name="signup" method="post" action="addsms.php?act=add"> <h1>SMS Detail Here!</h1>
    User Refrence Code:<input name="rfcd" type ="text" class="a" id="rfcd" placeholder="Enter Refrence Code" /><br>
    Total SMS Count: &nbsp &nbsp <input name="smsc" type ="text" class="a" id="smsc" placeholder="Enter SMS Count" /><br>
            Total SMS Amount: <input name="amnt" type ="text" class="a" id="amnt" placeholder="Enter SMS Amount" /><br>

<input type ="submit" Name="submit"  value="Submit" class="outset" />
</form>
```

**addsms.php**

```
   <?php
 require_once("./include/connect.php");
 require_once("./include/fg_membersite.php");


 if($_GET['act'] == 'add')
{
$rf_cd = $_POST['rfcd'];
$sms_c = $_POST['smsc'];
$am_nt = $_POST['amnt'];


  // echo $rf_cd;
  // exit;
    //I can Get value of variable  "$rf_cd"  at above line. while not able to get value in any function,





if ($rf_cd == NULL || $sms_c == NULL || $am_nt == NULL  )
{
    header("Location:sms.php?field=miss");

}




    else
        if(checkref_id_from_user() == true && checkref_id_from_user_data() == true )
            {

                  $get_detail = "select total_sms, total_sms_amount from user_data where ref_id = '$rf_cd'";
                  $res1 = Run($get_detail);

                    if(mysql_num_rows($res1) > 0){
                    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_object($res1)) {
                    $srn++;
                    $sms_oldcont = $rows->total_sms;
                    $sms_amnt_oldcont = $rows->total_sms_amount;
                    }
                    }

                    $inqry = "UPDATE user_data SET total_sms = '$sms_c' + '$sms_oldcont', total_sms_amount ='$am_nt'+ '$sms_amnt_oldcont' where ref_id = '$rf_cd' ";
                    $resinqry = Run($inqry);
                    if(!$resinqry)
                    {
                        echo $resinqry;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header("Location:sms.php?add=done");
                    }


            }

        else 
        if(checkref_id_from_user() == true && checkref_id_from_user_data() == false)
            {
                $inqry = "Insert into user_data (ref_id,total_sms,total_sms_amount) VALUES('$rf_cd','$sms_c','$am_nt')";
                $resinqry = Run($inqry);
                if(!$resinqry)
                {
        echo $resinqry;
                }
                else
                {
        header("Location:sms.php?add=done");
                }
            }

         // if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 && )
        else
        {
            header("Location:sms.php?refid=notavailable");
        }
    }

    else 
    {
        echo 'oh';
        //header("Location:sms.php?refid=notavailable");
    }





  function checkref_id_from_user(){

        $qry = "select ref_id from user where ref_id='".$rf_cd."'";
        echo $qry;
        $result = Run($qry);
        echo $result;
        exit;
        if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false; 

    }

    function checkref_id_from_user_data()
    {

        $checkrefid = "select ref_id from user_data where ref_id = '$rf_cd'";
        $res = Run($checkrefid);
        if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)
        {
        return true;
        }
        return false;

    }




?>
```

I can Get value of variable  "$rf_cd"  at any where in if condition. while not able to get value in any function,  "$rf_cd"  I wanna use this value in my functions to get info from database.

```
 $checkrefid = "select ref_id from user_data where ref_id = '$rf_cd'";
 echo  $checkrefid;
 exit
```

Above query shows the result that "Select ref_id from user_data where ref_id = '' ". 
while this should show the value of  variable $rf_cd.

Comment: variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: you need understand basic of how to pass argument to function and also pay attention to sql injeciton topic if you don't want someone to remove your db.

Comment: **WARNING**: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/) and for your sake I hope this is not on the public internet. You need to ensure any and all user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you are at serious risk of an application compromise. Whenever possible use prepared statements and placeholders to ensure you're not exposed to errors of that sort. If you've written your own database layer function called `Run` you're making a huge mistake.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can just declare $rf_cd as argument of those functions and pass it when calling them (best solution).

Also you can use "global" keyword to get an access to a $rf_cd variable from global scope.

```
function checkref_id_from_user(){
    global $rf_cd;
    ...
}

 function checkref_id_from_user_data() {
    global $rf_cd;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why not use `goto` instead of a function and make this 100% unmaintainable?

Comment: Well may be you should down the whole code just because it's buggy? There is "global" in php and it is still used in old legacy code. I offered different solutions.

Comment: @tadman i think global will not make that code worse than it is, but i guess the topic starter should know any way what is "global". Besides i clarified that the first solution (to pass variable as an argument to a function) is best and preferable way.

Comment: I like your first suggestion, but then you go and ignore your own advice and go with this `global` junk in your example, completely defeating your argument.

Answer (score -1):

Close your if statement `}` before your functions are read.  And for good form, I always list functions at the top of my scripts.

Comment: if I list my functions at top of my scripts this shows the same result which is my question. BTW I got solution by making that variable Global.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using global in the function?

If you wish for a function to have access to passive variables, you need to define them.

fx

```
myFunction() {
global $LoggedUser, $OtherGlobalVars
}
```

Comment: bad idea, why not just parse to the function?

Comment: I personally prefer to use the global for some variables as i have some functions that already are parsed alot of direct variables. Usually passive vars like the currenly logged in user.

Comment: I'm sorry, i dont get why you down-vote things due to a personal preference. the global scope is often used.

Comment: @MrGulerod Global variables are hugely messy, and unless you have an extremely good reason, their use should be avoided entirely. If you use global variables pervasively you will have conflicts, and these are very, very frustrating to debug. Do not recommend people use global variables casually. What you do in your own code-base is your concern, but this site tries to promote best practices.

Comment: Sorry. I was not aware that that global had these kind of issues.